# How to install ubuntu on an old mac-mini

Tags: mac-mini

I've got an old mac mini A1103, without airport, running on Mac OSX 10.5.8
I decided to install Ubuntu but I can't. Could anyone help me?
Which is the proper version for my mac?

my system:

1.25 Ghz PowerPC G4
512 Mb DDR SDRAM
37 Gb hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Try Xubuntu 12.04
The problem: booting with the CD gives bad graphics or a blank screen.

The solution: when booting, hold down alt. Select the “Windows” CD, not the “EFI” CD. This will get you to a blankish purple screen with a fuzzy icon of a keyboard on the bottom. Press F6 (NB: this will not work with an Apple Wireless keyboard. Use a wired keyboard). Pick a language. Press the down key to select “Install Ubuntu“. Now press F6 again, and select nomodeset by using the arrow keys and the space bar. Press escape, and the menu should close. Towards the bottom of the screen there’s a boot line and a cursor… use the arrow keys to scroll left until you’re just left of “quiet” and “splash” (actually, you can delete those words). Type “nomodeset xforcevesa“. Press enter to boot. Wait. Keep waiting. Nothing’s happening? Keep waiting. It took about 5 minutes for my Mac Mini to move on, upon which it started whirring and clicking. Hurray!

Post-install: your system won’t boot, unless you edit the boot commands at grub. Add nomodeset xforcevesa again (press ‘e’ when you’re at grub to edit a boot command). Once it boots, install the NVIDIA proprietary drivers. Edit /etc/default/grub to add nomodeset noacpi reboot=acpi in the appropriate place. Save the file, then run update-grub. Reboot. Your graphics may still suck. Run nvidia-xconfig and reboot.

good luck

Sources: dustin.li